# Как правильно получать ссылки на сайт?

Tags: seo

Есть сайт. Нужно прокачать главную страницу. Но при этом есть ещё страницы статей. Для продвижения получать ссылки на сайт можно только на главную страницу или нужно обязательно и на другие страницы?

Comment: Гуглер Google's Gary Illyes о важных сигналах поиска Гугл в 2017 году http://searchengineland.com/google-whats-important-2017-machine-learning-amp-structured-data-261150 . Там нет упоминаний о ссылках. Гуглер John Mueller: Связь с веб-сайтами высокого авторитета не помогают с SEO https://www.seroundtable.com/google-linking-to-high-authority-seo-23461.html

Comment: На статьи тоже нужны ссылки, в идеале - с продвигаемыми ключами в анкорах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Линкбилдинг для буржунета](https://siteclinic.ru/blog/external-optimization/linkbuilding-dlya-burguneta/) - достаточно неплохая статья по линкбилдингу в бурже, но вполне подходит и для наших реалий.
По поводу "можно только на главную?" - можно только на главную. Однако чем больше получит "ссылок" необходимая страница, тем больше веса она будет иметь и, как следствие, выше ранжироваться.[Ещё одна статья на тему правильного наращивания ссылочной массы](https://serpstat.com/ru/blog/right-link-building/)